# Rails truncate helper with index and separator

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a method similar to the Rails [truncate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) method that accepts an **index** where I can indicate the start of truncation and a **separator** parameter so that it does not start in the middle of a word or string?

For example:

"i love the taste of bubble tea after lunch."

I would like to grab a string of size 15 starting from index 9 so this should result in:

"the taste of bubble"

Comment: I'm not sure why what you're describing isn't what `truncate` does. Are you trying to remove characters from the beginning of the word instead of the end? Are you trying to get **at least** `index` number of characters instead of **at most** `index` characters? Could you give an example of the input you have and the output you want to have?

Comment: I'm looking to substring the original string with removal of characters from the beginning and the end.  At least index number of characters is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is one function to do this, so you'll have to write your own. I'd recommend chopping off the start of the string first and then using `truncate` to handle the end. Something like this might do what you want:

```
def truncate_beginning_and_end(str, beginning, length, separator)
  first_space_before_beginning = str[0..beginning].rindex(separator)
  str_without_beginning = str[(first_space_before_beginning + 1)..-1]
  truncate(str_without_beginning, length: length, separator: separator, omission: '')
end
```